# Extending String.prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I've started to make my string-related function as extension methods in JavaScript,

My issue is when I add an extension method like below, the method works but it doesn't show up in the Intellisense of VS Code.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    let str = this.toString()
    if (arguments.length) {
        const type = typeof arguments[0]
        const args = type === 'string' || type === 'number' ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0]

        for (const arg in args) str = str.replace(new RegExp(`\\{${arg}\\}`, 'gi'), args[arg])
    }
    return str
}
```

As an example, if I define the extension in a .js file and then import the file, I'm expecting to see the method like **"test".format** but I don't see the method.

Comment: On a side note, it's usually not recommended to modify prototypes you don't own, see https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/.

Comment: Have you tried adding Format as a String method in a Type Declaration.d.ts file?

Answer (score 4):

Create a file `index.d.ts` that contains the type declaration of your function :

```
interface String {
    format(): string;
}
```

For more information see [JavaScript Language Service in Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: That's for Typescript. I am after a way with pure JS.

Comment: No, in visual studio code it's for javascript also. From the docs : `Because JavaScript and TypeScript are now based on the same language service, they are able to interact in a richer way. For example, JavaScript IntelliSense can be provided for values declared in a .d.ts file`

Comment: For simple functions you can use JSDoc. But for more complicated stuff, like your example JSDoc does not work well.